# Asp.net data listing

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to list data with repeater from database on a server. There are nearly 5000 data in the database. When listing this data with repeater, the page loads a bit late. How can I quickly list data?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't try to display so much data in one list.

No user is going to scroll through 5000+ records to find the one they want.

Use paging, and provide options for the user to filter the returned data.

**NB:** Whilst you *can* add paging support to the `Repeater` control, it's not supported by default. You would probably have better luck using [the `ListView` control instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview), combined with [a `DataPager` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager).

Comment: I'm using jquery datatable. Paging is done automatically. Isn't it correct to use it this way? Can't we find a solution using datatable?

Comment: From the sounds of it, you're returning a table containing 5000 rows, and then using a Javascript solution to break that up into pages. It would be better to return an empty table, and then use [the DataTables AJAX support](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) to load each page of data on demand.

Comment: I agree - use a list view, and the datapager. You can't (don't want) to pull 5,000 records. You can do this your self, or use a listview and the built in datapager. It will limit the records pulled client side, and will quite much run instant, but MORE important, save you having to write any paging code yourself. It quite much built in, and will cost you about 3 extra line of code in the paging event.